# openerp add custom field in BOM but always error

Tags: openerp-7

I want to few custom field in mrp.bom table in order to calculate the real row material consumption starting from drawing dimensions.
here is my .py code

```
from osv import osv, fields
```

class mrp_bom(osv.osv):

```
_inerhit = 'mrp.bom'

#_name = 'mrp.bom'

_columns = {
        'Residuo_barra': fields.float(string='Residuo Barra', required=False),
        'Sfrido': fields.float(string='Sfrido mm', required=False),
        'L_barra': fields.float(string='lunghezza barra mm', required=False),
        'L_pezzo_a_disegno': fields.float(string='L a disegno in mm', required=False),
        'L_pezzo_calcolata': fields.float(string='Lunghezza calcolata', required=False),
}

_defaults = {
    'Residuo_barra': 300.0,
    'Sfrido': 4.0,
    'L_barra': 3000.0,
}

def button_Calcola(self, cr, uid, ids, L_pezzo_a_disegno, Residuo_barra, Sfrido, L_barra, conext=None):
    #calcola il consumo effettivo della barra
    barra_utile = L_barra - Residuo_barra
    numero_pezzi = int(barra_utile / (L_pezzo_a_disegno + Sfrido))
    res = {
        'L_pezzo_calcolata': (L_barra / numero_pezzi)
    }

    return {'value': res}
```

mrp_bom()

and here is the .xml

```
    <record id="mrp_bom_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.tree</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_tree_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="product_id" position="after">
            <field name="L_pezzo_calcolata" />
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="mrp_bom_component_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.component.tree</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_component_tree_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="product_id" position="after">
            <field name="L_pezzo_calcolata" />
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="mrp_bom_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.form</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='bom_lines']/tree" position="inside" >
            <field name="Residuo_barra" />
            <field name="Sfrido" />
            <field name="L_barra" />
            <field name="L_pezzo_a_disegno" />
            <field name="L_pezzo_calcolata" />
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

</data>
```

during the installation process I get :

ValidateError

Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!

If I check into the module structure Setting\Database structure\models\mrp_bom 
the field have been added, But If I menage view in bom view the fields are not available!

Answer (score 0):

Change the record id of inherited views so they are not the same.

For example:

```
<record id="mrp_bom_tree_view_add_field_L_pezzo_calcolata" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mrp_bom_tree_view_add_field_L_pezzo_calcolata</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.bom</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_bom_tree_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="product_id" position="after">
        <field name="L_pezzo_calcolata" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```